# C#, не могу получить права на папку в Program Files

Tags: c#, uac

Изменил у приложения в app.manifest эту строчку

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

на эту

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Программа пытается запись новый файл в директорию в Program Files, но выдается ошибка: "Отказано в доступе по пути \"c:\Program Files (x86)\aaa\aaa.exe\".".

Если меняю права на папку у группы "Пользователи (pc/Пользователи)", то получается, но изначально там права не стояли (на запись и изменение), получается мои изменения в app.manifest никак не влияют, запуск идет от пользователей а не от администратора, но почему так? UAC у меня отключен, поэтому при запуске сообщения о запуске от имени администратора не выводится, а если включить, то все равно не выводится при запуске приложения, такое чувство что изменения в app.manifest игнорятся. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: запускаете из студии или отдельно?

Comment: Кстати если запускать не из студии, а уже сккомпилированный exe ошибки не выдается, но и копирования не происходит

Comment: rdorn - из студии вот та что я описал ситуацию, а вот без студии сам exe, как нписал выше ошибки нет, но и копирования не происходит.

Comment: aaa.exe не файл который выполняет действие! Я не сам себя запущенного перезаписываю. Там может быть любой файл, и будет ошибка на запись или на удаление имеющихся в program files файлов.

Comment: если верить этому http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/articles/admin.php то должно быть все правильно, сейчас проверю, отпишусь по факту

Comment: ну вообще в Program Files никому кроме установщика и админа писать и нельзя по идее, даже админу с большими оговорками можно. А еще проверьте что вам антивирус не "помогает", они тоже имеют привычку вмешиваться молча, если руками не настраивали

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/9Q7eZkGGpzHD9

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/YAjcBBKwpzHCC

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/SExwI2P_pzHG8

Comment: Антивирус Nod 32, щас попробую выключить.

Comment: Не помогло отключение.

Comment: rdom, но мои изменения должны же давать возможность и без прав админа, хотя-бы эти права запрашивать что-ли у запускающего. А он молча либо не делает, либо выдает ошибку.

Comment: ну что, эксперимент подтвердил, при внедрении манифеста с требованием повышения прав и автономном запуске релизной сборки все отработало как положено, каспер тоже выдал все свои предупреждения, файл записался.

Comment: выложите манифест, может там что-то не так

Comment: Да я тут потестил, действительно изменения есть, видимо то что программа не выполняет свои дейсвтия (копирование), проблема в другом (молча закрывается и все). Вопрос только а чего при запуске из студии, F5 манифест не применяется?

Comment: повышение прав происходит, но для студии. это в последнем абзаце по ссылке выше

Comment: собственно так и должно быть, т.к. при запуске из студии ваша программа запускается не самостоятельно, а в контексте отладчика.

Comment: Да это я все понял теперь. Теперь осталось понять почему уже скомпилированное приложение не копирует файлы и молча закрывается (оно и должно закрываться, но все же почему не копируются файлы).

Comment: rdom, разобрался и с этой проблемой. Спасибо за помощь. Ваш комменатрий стал самым ценным, в этом была причина: "так и должно быть, т.к. при запуске из студии ваша программа запускается не самостоятельно, а в контексте отладчика"

Comment: хорошо что разобрались =)

Answer (score 1):

> [@rdorn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198316/rdorn): *так и должно быть, т.к. при запуске из студии ваша программа*
>   *запускается не самостоятельно, а в контексте отладчика*

запускайте скомпилированный *exe*, а не из студии.